# How to cast a result set into an array?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-8.4

I'm using `PostgreSQL 8.4` and writing a function as follows. I came across an issue, how to cast a result set into an array. I mean, imagine I have a query returning only one column of type integer, like

```
SELECT amount from daily_profit;
```

I've been trying to write something like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fill_daily_profit() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    arr integer[] := cast ((SELECT amount from partner.daily_profit) as integer[]);     
    -- doesn't work, the following error was produced:
    -- cannot cast type integer to integer[]
BEGIN
END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Postgres 8.4 is no longer maintained (=supported) you should plan an upgrade to the current version as soon as possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know, but in our production invironment it's not possible now. But the task must be done using 8.4...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest a simpler and faster **[ARRAY constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS)** for this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fill_daily_profit()
 RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   arr integer[] := ARRAY (SELECT amount FROM partner_daily_profit);
BEGIN
   ...
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Add an `ORDER BY` clause to the `SELECT` if you want elements in a particular order.

**However**, There is often a set-based solution around the corner that voids the need for such an array a priori.

Answer (score 2):

You need to aggregate the values into an array:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fill_daily_profit() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    arr integer[];     
BEGIN
  select array_agg(amount)
     into arr
  from partner_daily_profit;
END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```